# Outputing a created object in javascript to a server side JSON file

Tags: javascript, python, django, server, client

I want to create a JSON file filled with an object that the client requests by "post" method.

I've tried to assign value to an HTML tag, and access it from my views.py function.

HTML file code:

```
<script>

    var myobj = {};

    {% for f in foos %}
        {% for g in goos %}
            myobj["{{ g }}_{{ f }}"] = "{{ g.name }} {{ f.name }}"
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

    document.getElementById('myobj').value = myobj; </script>
```

views.py file code:

```
def out_to_json(request):
    f = open(r"\main\jsons\first.json",'w+')
    _obj = request.POST['myobj']
    f.write(str(_obj))
    f.close()
```

The result in my JSON file is [object Object].

Is running through all keys of **myobj** is necessary to access each value separately?

I except the output of the full object as it is in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myobj is a JavaScript object, not a string in JSON notation which is what you need. You have to use `JSON.stringify(myobj)`.

[JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)